# VSTS in release management how to retrieve the last commit message

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I know that in Build tasks you can get the commit message using **$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)**, but what if you wanna get the same message from a Release task ?

Or how can I pass a that value as variable to the release pipeline ? thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve it using the REST API. You have the build ID, so you can easily make a REST API call to retrieve the commit message of the commit for that build.

However, let me leave you with some food for thought. I have no idea what you're doing with the commit message, so the following may not be relevant, but in case it is...

- What if there are multiple commits between builds? You'll only get the **latest** commit message, not the commit messages for the commits that weren't built.
- What if there are multiple builds between releases?
- What if there are multiple releases, but most builds don't go to every environment? E.g. Environment 2 is 10 builds behind Environment 1.

If there is anything less than a 1 to 1 relationship between commit, builds, releases, and releases to every environment in the pipeline of that release, you are going to end up missing commit messages. Probably most of them, especially in higher environments in your release pipeline (even if every build is deployed to the first environment in your pipeline, most builds will probably not be promoted to the last environment in your pipeline).

Comment: I needed to add a condition based on commit message but you are right ! ... I would have a mess if I take that approach, I ended up using a powershell script to test if an artifact was generated or not .... if not .... the task will be skipped in release management. (Note: My build pipeline publish artifacts based on a word in the commit message, that's why I was trying to use the same logic at the RM but my solution was clean and fast :D thank you so much for your answer, it made me think different about my problem)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Variable (de|re)Hydration Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.variablehydration) by Martin Hinshelwood.

These tasks basically allow you to export a subset of variables to a JSON file in a build, publish it as an artifact and import the variables again from the JSON in your release. I use these tasks often in combination with GitVersion to get detailed version information from my builds to my releases.

Comment: Thank you I'm gonna test it :D, weird google didn't bring me that extension in the search results !

Answer (score 1):

You can add an *agentless phase*
[image: Agentless phase]

and add a Invoke REST API Task.[image]

Another idea could be that you get the message with $(Build.SourceVersionMessage) and make it available to a release process as an artifact for example written in plain text file created during the build and published with the Publish artifact Task.